# I bought cases and some keys on CS:GO and when i open up my inventory its not there

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Does anyone know the answer to this? Do you need like a certain level or idk?

Comment: There's no levelling system in CS:GO. Plus, we're not sure if we can help with this considering that this might be something to take to Steam support.

Comment: @Texenox uhmm [actually there is](http://ardao.me/files/2qz.png). [Blog post:](http://www.counter-strike.net/operationbloodhound/) "[...] all-new XP-driven profile Ranks [...]"

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](https://steamstat.us/) on the CS:GO section, the inventory is delayed at the moment. Please wait and it'll fix itself.

[image: Picture from steamstat.us]